# Problem with PHP strip tag

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I am trying to get my site feed working.

I need to select some content and display in my feed. After selecting, i strip tags then display.

The problem is this:

The data still displays as if the tags still exist (but no visible html tag) eg. after stripping, in my source ill have:

Hello (just illustrating)

----There will be gap in between as if html character still exist, but cant see any when i view my source-----

Hi

How can i fix this . Thanks

**EDIT:**

To make it clearer, after stripping i still get text like this:

This is my first line

This is my second line with a gap in between the first line and second line as if there is a paragraph tag

**UPDATE**

i am using this:

$body=substr(strip_tags(preg_replace('/\n{2,}/',"\n",$row["post_content"])),0,150);

when i echo $body, it still maintains new lines

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Can you show a real-life example?

Comment: I do not understand..could you be clear?sorry

Comment: are the tags on separate lines initially? it may be new lines... \n

Comment: @ Pekka , @luca , @trey ; have added an illustration.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to do all the strip tags and what not. Without code it's difficult if not impossible to help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may have a `\n` which was at the end of the paragraphs after the closing tags you stripped.

```
preg_replace('/[\p{Z}\s]{2,}/s',' ',$string);
```

will strip out all `white space`, `tabs`, `new lines` and `double spaces` and replace with single space.

`\s` Matches any white-space character. Equivalent to the Unicode character categories `[\f\n\r\t\v\x85\p{Z}]`. If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified with the ECMAScript option, `\s` is equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v]`.

Answer (score 1):

strip_tags will literally strip the tags, leaving any other whitespace behind.
You could get rid of extra newlines and whitespace with regular expressions, but depending on your content, you might mangle it.

Remove newlines:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/',"\n",$string);
```

Remove extra spaces:

```
$string = preg_replace('/ {2,}/',' ',$string);
```

Comment: Actually I'd trim any whitespace _BEFORE_ you strip the tags as you might also be trimming the wrong whitespace. There may be new lines in the content. But to be honest, that is actually tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing some very annoyingly similar. Solved with trim

```
    $body=strip_tags(trim($row["post_content"]));
```

Comment: Trim does not remove whitespace on multi line strings.